# how convert date format in javascript reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

```
<b>Select Datetime</b><br/>
<DateTimeField onChange={this.clockevent} format={"x"}/>   

clockevent=(newDate)=>{
    var dateVal ="/Date("+newDate+")/";
    var date = new Date(parseFloat(dateVal.substr(6)));


    console.log(
    date.getFullYear() + " " +
    (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
    date.getDate() + "  " +

    date.getHours() + ":" +
    date.getMinutes() + ":" +
    date.getSeconds() );
}
```

result :

> 2018/2/1  14:16:0

i want the result add day,month and ss '  format (**DD MM ss**) i want to this format =

> 2018/02/01  14:16:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I haven't found the way to format YYYY/MM/DD as you asked but I have the 2-digit format.

```js
const today = Date.now();

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(today));
```

Comment: That's great! Glad I helped!

Comment: but result  , 01.02.2018 14:48:00  i try sequential : 20180201144800 like this, is it possible?

Comment: Format YYYY/MM/DD :: new Intl.DateTimeFormat( 'fr-ca' ).format( new Date( ) ).replace(/-/g,'/');

Answer (score 19):

## Use date-fns library

for "2018/02/01 14:16:00" this format use the following code

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
console.log(format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss'))
```

with this you can customize your own format.

[date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns)

[For customizing date format use this](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/javascript-dates-manipulation-with-date-fns/)

Comment: This is the simplest and shortest way

Comment: It would be nice to add plugin link, so that viewer doesn't need to search for it.

Answer (score 8):

I found the easiest solution for the React.js developer.

In my schema(In the backend) date format was like this.

```
createdAt: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now()
}
```

It will give me output as `2019-04-30T08:59:00.000Z` which is `(YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:SS.SSSZ)` format.
To change the date format in Frontend you can easily solve the problem using

```
1. npm install dateformat
2. import dateFormat from 'dateformat';
3. dateFormat("2019-04-30T08:59:00.000Z", "mmmm dS, yyyy") to get April 30th, 2019
or dateFormat("2019-04-30T08:59:00.000Z", "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy") to get Tuesday, April 30th, 2019.
```

Comment: you can add some link to see all the documentation and implementation. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Answer (score 3):

Just use moment and define the format as below

```
moment(yourDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD kk:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Moment.js no longer maintained, please read their announcement here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateformat lib (https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat) , it has so many options that can help you , and it's easy to use , you can use it in front-end or back-end , it worked fine for me 
here an example :

```
dateFormat(expirationdate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  i did.  
        var dateVal ="/Date("+newDate+")/";
        var date = new Date(parseFloat(dateVal.substr(6)));
        const YYYY = date.getFullYear();
        let DD = date.getMonth()+1;
        let MM = date.getDate();
        let HH = date.getHours() ;
        let mm = date.getMinutes()
        let ss = date.getSeconds();


        if(DD<10)
        {
            DD=`0${DD}`;
        }
        if(MM<10)
        {
            MM=`0${MM}`;
        }

        if(HH<10)
        {
            HH=`0${HH}`;
        }
        if(mm<10)
        {
            mm=`0${mm}`;
        }
        if(ss<10)
        {
            ss=`0${ss}`;
        }

        const ltime= (YYYY+DD+MM+HH+mm+ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Moment JS** provide control on each date string and you can easily convert into another format easily.

**Install Moment Package:**

```
npm install --save moment
```

**Convert date format using moment:**

```
import Moment from 'moment';
  
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  
    this.state = {
      dateDMY: Moment("1994-07-01").format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      dateMDY: Moment("1994-07-01").format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
      dateYMD: Moment("01-07-1994").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> DMY Format: { this.state.dateDMY } </p>
        <p> MDY Format: { this.state.dateMDY } </p>
        <p> YMD Format: { this.state.dateYMD } </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
   
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Output:**

```
DMY Format: 01-07-1994
MDY Format: 07-01-1994
YMD Format: 1994-01-07
```

Comment: momentjs is no longer maintained

Comment: We can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns as an alternative to `moment-js`

Answer (score 0):

Since moment is no longer maintained, you can now use [dayjs](https://day.js.org/):

```
dayjs("2019-04-30T08:59:00.000Z").format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score -1):

I used below logic, It may help you.

```
{new Date(your date).toLocaleString("lookup")}
```